# Automatically create contact record in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have migrated contact records in marketing cloud data extension and it is constantly updated. We need to have those customer details in all contacts  with memberId as contact key.
Can we automate to create these contacts as it is added in the data extension?

Comment: Hi there, you can do this a number of ways. To better answer your question, can you give some more information: is this a once off and an ongoing activity? How is the Customer Data Extension being updated (FTP upload, API, etc)? Is it just customer additions, or also customer Updates (like email changes) also?

Comment: Additional: have you migrated from other salesforce products to Marketing cloud or any other System ?

Comment: Hi, DE is updated via FTP and there is a possibility that emails are updated. One time import is done using csv file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the FTP, then you can use the same file in FTP to import Subscribers [Email - Contacts] via Import File activity, to the "All Subscribers" as below.

Make sure your file has the Mandatory values such as Subscriber Key [memberId], Emiladdress 
and Status [as 'Active']

Example CSV:
[image]

[image]

Once they are added to all Subscribers, they automatically gets added to Contacts, specifically for Email channel.

As Best practice and to double confirm on mapping, use map manually option as below,

[image]

Finally as per your requirement you can put this Import definition in a Automation either as File drop or as a Scheduled as per your requirement!
Hope this help!